# localhost crash before lauch, middleware nodeJs problem

Tags: express, middleware, multer

it looks normal
app.js

```
const path = require("path")

const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const multer = require("multer")

const feedRoutes = require("./routes/feed")


const app = express()

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images") //images folder
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname)
    },
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || file.mimetype === "image/jpeg") {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: fileStorage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
})

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    next()
})

// app.use(upload)

app.use("/feed", feedRoutes)

// error handling
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(error)
    const status = error.statusCode
    const message = error.message
    res.status(status).json({
        message: message
    })
})

mongoose.
    connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
.then(result => {
    app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Succesfull connect to database, server is listening at 8080"))
}).catch(err => console.log("cant reach database, server error", err))
```

but the app crashed, here the respond from terminal:

```
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (/home/agungwahyudi/Documents/pratice/rest-api/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/agungwahyudi/Documents/pratice/rest-api/backend/app.js:46:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

I know the it's app.use(upload) made it crash but i don't know how to fix it

i try to write

```
app.use(multer({storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter})
```

but still crashed

Comment: I suggest you pay closer attention to the Multer docs ~ https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme

Comment: Are you sure it is on multer, i read the error log its on line 46, which is `app.use("/feed", feedRoutes)`, how does the feedRoutes configurated. I usually occurs this error on router too. **Edit**: i saw `app.use(upload)` is commented, does the error still occur after comment this line?

Comment: my mistake, the multer shall not write in app.js. I just read the multer docs. It backs to normal now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `upload` like middleware

```
app.get("/upload", upload.single(), (req, res) => {
  doSomething
})
```